# How to save variables values

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML file with some `input` and `select` tags. I want to be able to use the value of these forms in an algorithm.

The problem is that when I output the `bk8` a `NaN` appears instead of the `bk8` value. Also, I want to be able to use all these variables values other pages. 
Can you help me with that?
Thank you in advance

```html
<input type="number" style="text-align: center;" name="weight">
<div id="text"></div>
```

```js
var d6;
var bk4 = 39.373127;
var bk5 = 66.118203;
var bk6 = 0.14327702;
var bk7;
var bk8;
var bk11;
var ae11;
var af19;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('input[name="weight"]').change(function() {
      d6 = ($('select[name="dose"]').val()) / ($('input[name="weight"]').val());
    });
    $('input[name="weight"]').change(function() {
      bk8 = (((d6 / 50) * (39.373127 / 0.14327702)) + ((d6 / 50) * (66.118203 / bk7)));
    });
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = bk8;
  });
```

Comment: The issue is because you are displaying the value of `bk8` on page load when it has no value. The `bk8` value will also always be `NaN` because it relies on `bk7` which also has no value set. You only set the value of `bk8` in the `change` event handler. You have a couple of other syntax issues; your code is missing a closing `})` , has nested document.ready handlers (one of which you should remove), you're assigning two `change` handlers to the same element, and there doesn't appear to be a `select[name="dose"]` element in the code you've shown so we can't verify your algorithm at all.

Comment: Finally, if you want to use these values on multiple locations in your site, put the logic in an external JS file and include that on the relevant pages.

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with an `input` and a `select`. And i assigned `bk7=1;` because it was never set.

> I would **always** give my **variables** a **default value**. If you don't do that,
>   you have to check if they have a value, before you use them.

At the moment the `div` with `id="text"` is not changed when the `select` is changed.

```js
var d6 = 1;
var bk4 = 39.373127;
var bk5 = 66.118203;
var bk6 = 0.14327702;
var bk7 = 1;
var bk8 = 1;
var bk11 = 1;
var ae11 = 1;
var af19 = 1;

$('input[name="weight"]').change(function() {
  d6 = ($('select[name="dose"]').val()) / ($('input[name="weight"]').val());
  bk8 = (((d6 / 50) * (39.373127 / 0.14327702)) + ((d6 / 50) * (66.118203 / bk7)));
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = bk8;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" style="text-align: center;" name="weight">
<select style="text-align: center;" name="dose">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option> 
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: if this is a good solution you can mark my answere as solution.